# Multiple swagger instances for a single application using springdoc

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I want to have two swagger interfaces for the same springboot application like,

/api/auth/swagger-ui.html

/api/leagcy/swagger-ui.html

I am using this dependency

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.0</version>
     </dependency>
```

I was able to achieve something similar by defining groups.

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi userOpenApi() {
        String packagesToscan[] = {"example.auth"};
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("auth").packagesToScan(packagesToscan)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi legacyOpenApi() {
        String packagesToscan[] = {"example.legacy"};
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().group("legacy").packagesToScan(packagesToscan)
                .build();
    }
}
```

This will result into two interfaces like,

127.0.0.1:8091/swagger-ui/swagger-ui/index.html?urls.primaryName=legacy

127.0.0.1:8091/swagger-ui/swagger-ui/index.html?urls.primaryName=auth

But the problem here is, it is showing a dropdown to switch between two interfaces.
[image]
I want to get rid of this dropdown.

Can someone help on this?